# Visual Studio 2015 Moving AspNet.Identity into class library

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-identity

I've moved AspNet.Identity into a class library many times in VS 2013, but in VS 2015, the compiler complains about the manager parameter throwing this exception

> The type 'MyNamespace.ApplicationUser' cannot be used as type parameter 'TUser' in the generic type or method 'UserManager'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'MyNamespace.ApplicationUser' to 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUser

in this code:

```
public class ApplicationUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

All my references and using statements are the same.

What's going on?

Comment: What does your ApplicationUser class look like?

Comment: @GaryMcGill I updated the code to include the ApplicationUser class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to make your ApplicationUser inherit from IdentityUser.